# Specifying dynamic properties for an object in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, solr

I'm looking for a best practice to hold a dynamic set of properties for an object. The idea is to have a base object `Person` and allow users to add properties to it.

For example, I have a Person which has the basic properties of `FirstName`, `LastName`. `User1` will add `HairColor` as `string` and `User2` will add `Height` as `int`.

The point is to allow users to take the core object and dynamically add properties to it to match their needs, then I would want to persist it to DB and allow searching for those properties (`MSSQL` and `SOLR`).

Comment: Have you looked at `ExpandoObject`?

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks, I have, but not sure how it persists, especially when considering SOLR indices.

Comment: can you better explain your problem with SOLR, to someone who does not know what it is?

Comment: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Mapping.md#fully-loose-mapping

Comment: @LuisFilipe, I was under the impression that SOLR doesn't support loose mapping, but apparently it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From .Net 4.0 There is the `ExpandoObject` - that'll be your choice!

Before .Net 4.0 You can wrap a nice class with an hidden `Dictionary<string, object>` to hold your properties

**EDIT** Sample Code

In the sample below we create a class with some known properties and an expandable `ExtraProperties`

At the end we can iterate the `ExpandoObject` to get all its dynamically added values:

*Note: `ExpandoObject` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.ExtraProperties.HairColor = "Green";
        p1.ExtraProperties.DateOfGraduation = DateTime.UtcNow;    

        foreach (var prop in p1.ExtraProperties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Key + ": " + prop.Value);
        }

    }
}

public class Person
{
    private System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject _extraProperties = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BornDate { get; set; }

    public dynamic ExtraProperties
    {
        get { return _extraProperties; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

And to get the Expando Object to Solr you could use Sornet with fully loose mapping.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar use case I've solved with this class

```
public class User
{
    #region Private Fields

    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the field names.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The field names.
    /// </value>
    public IEnumerable<string> FieldNames
    {
        get { return _keyValues.Keys; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the <see cref="System.String" /> for the specified fieldName.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The <see cref="System.String" />.
    /// </value>
    /// <param name="fieldName">The field name.</param>
    /// <returns>The value for the field if it could be found; otherwise null</returns>
    public string this[string fieldName]
    {
        get
        {
            string value;
            return _keyValues.TryGetValue(fieldName, out value) ? value : null;
        }
        set { _keyValues.Add(fieldName, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns a <see cref="System.String" /> that represents this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    ///     A <see cref="System.String" /> that represents this instance.
    /// </returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string res = string.Empty;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in _keyValues)
        {
            res += string.Format("{0}={1};", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
        return res.TrimEnd(';');
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Note that all properties will be of type string this case. All properties can be accessed with an indexer with e.g. user["Name"]

Comment: That is a nice solution previous to .Net4.0; From then on just use the ExpandoObject

Comment: Why hold only strings and not allow object?

Comment: @LuisFilipe Indeed, I've used it with .NET 3.5. I justed needed string values and didn't want the dictionary to hold 'object' as value to avoid casting and type checks.